# pgadmin3 install on CentOS7

Tags: installation, centos7, pgadmin

I am using CentOS7 and PostgreSQL-13. As it is very difficult to work database-related queries in the command line I want to install pgadmin3. Aas it is available on the yum repository and in my CentOS, I do not have any internet connection. So I have installed pgadmin3 with the following installation command only: `yum install pgadmin3`.

I have seen in some tutorials they modified the `sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh` file. But I did not find such a file in my CentOS machine after pgadmin3 installation. Now I have no idea how to configure it with my already installed PostgreSQL-13 and httpd and how I can use this. I have not found any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL-13 not supported for pgadmin3, you must install pgadmin4